# npapi full screen

Tags: webkit, fullscreen, npapi

I have a npapi plugin working on WebKit. How do I get it to work fullscreen? Is setting the screen browser`s or plugin`s job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API in NPAPI to go full-screen, so you have to do that yourself by opening a native window and using native platform APIs to make it full screen, then do your drawing there.

Comment: Just to make sure that I got it right: it is plugin`s job to open the native window, right?

Comment: Right, that's not part of NPAPI either. Be aware that Safari explicitly recommends against doing this in your plugin though: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/Tasks/NetscapePlugins.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001250-DontLinkElementID_1